# How to call "sed" on PDF files

Tags: pdf, sed

I am able to find text on PDF files using `pdfgrep`. How can I `sed` them? I just want to change a pattern of text and I don't think I need a editor for that. Or do I?

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You need a PDF editor to change text in a PDF.

Searching for a piece of text in PDFs is much more straightforward than replacing it. PDFtk or PDFedit might have an API.

Comment: I see. The fact that pdfgrep can find the text makes me think that could be a too to replace the text. I will try with PDFtk. Thanks!

Comment: nope. I'm afraid PDFs are a binary format, so in order to make a change to it, the file would have to be recompiled.